# google map cannot show in first time

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-maps

I have the google map on popup. When I have added this line `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/mapps/assets/js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>` , it has some abnormal thing. e.g. When the page first load and click the button to popup the google map. It shows as below:
[image: Cannot show google map in first time screen]

When I click the enlarge button, it shows below:
[image: Click enlarge button and show this screen]

After that, I press esc and show below: 
[image: Show correct afterwards]

[image: Upload the javascript error screen]

Comment: I think you need to re-initialize the map once the popup is already loaded.

Comment: tried but still cannot show. Still need to click enlarge button to show.

Comment: can you replicate this issue using web?

Comment: Hi rafon, what is using web? is it using desktop web browser? Same happen on desktop.

Comment: try to add some timer, like in javascript setTimeout() before initializing the map

Comment: Hi rafon, I will try to google it on setTimeout. On the other hand, when I press F12, the map will show. Is there any mysterious?

Comment: You should try to fix that error first. I have a feeling that is the cause of your problem.